# Updating comments with references in .po translation

Tags: localization, translation, poedit

I'm currently working with some translation files for an application. Each translatable string has a comment (with reference to where the string is being used), the original string, and the translation. Like this format:

```
#: src/view/screens/Settings/index.tsx:721
msgid "Account"
msgstr ""
```

This works fine to translate in the GUI of POEdit. The problem occurs when there are updates to the application. Then the comments with reference are likely to be changed due to changes to the code. I can easily update the language file to get the new strings from the updated original language file ("Translations"->"Update from POT-file" in the menu). The new strings are added, but comments doesn't seem to be updated. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> The new strings are added, but comments doesn't seem to be updated.

They are. Fully syncing with the reference POT file is the whole point of that operation.

If you think it doesn't work, please file a bug including detailed description of your environment, versions of things and a self-contained reproduction test case.